# What is the green version of php?

Tags: php, php-7

I am not sure whether it is appropriate to ask such question here. But I wonder what this green version of php means. I saw the term around the internet after PHP 7 was released, but I did not see any explanation on why PHP 7 was called Green Version of PHP.

Comment: Probably because these colors: http://php.net/supported-versions.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One reason is that the efficiency of the language has been improved e.g. in terms of reduced CPU cycles and better memory management. When you are running a large website, this equates to less servers needed to run your site, which means lower electricity bills and so is better for the environment (and your profit margin :)). See e.g. http://www.infoworld.com/article/2912902/php/coming-soon-php-7-and-its-a-scorcher.html

> The new version features engine improvements, lower memory usage, and native local thread storage. In fact, PHP 7's reduced need for servers makes it the environmentally sound choice, Lerdorf stressed. "Just in terms of being green, PHP 7 should pretty much be an essential upgrade for anybody who is running a lot of servers."

Answer (score 3):

Presumably because the actively supported versions are colored green on the [Supported Versions](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) page @ php.net.